# c++ pass struct to a function

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

First of all this is my class assignment and I already pulled all my hair off and decided to ask you guys for a help. So, I have a txt file that has some structured info in it (string, double, string, double...) and I need to read it into an array of structs. That part of code works ok. But when I put it a separate function and try to call it nothing works. I assume that values that I pass into function are written wrong. Please point me where I messed up. Thank you very much in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int numberOfItems;

ifstream inFile;

struct menuItemType
{
    string menuItem;
    double menuPrice;
};

void showMenu(menuItemType, int&);
int getData(ifstream, menuItemType*, int);

int main()
{
    menuItemType *menuList;

    menuList = new menuItemType[numberOfItems];

    int getData(ifstream inFile, menuItemType* menuList, int numberOfItems);

    cout << "Test\n";

    return 0;
}

// Get Data from txt file
int getData(ifstream inFile, menuItemType* menuList, int numberOfItems)
{

    int counter;
    string s;

    inFile.open("test.txt");

    for (counter = 0; counter < numberOfItems; counter++)
    {
        getline(inFile, s);
        menuList[counter].menuItem = s;
        inFile.ignore();
        inFile >> menuList[counter].menuPrice;
        inFile.ignore();
    }

    inFile.close();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You aren't initialising `numberOfItems`, you are redeclaring `getData` instead of calling it, and even if you were to call it, it won't compile because streams cannot be copied.

Comment: It compiles with no errors. numberOfItems is suppose to be initialized in getData function.

Comment: @YuriiGul The code above does, sure, but it doesn't attempt to do what you think it does. Try actually calling the function with something like `ifstream file; getData(file, menuList, numberOfItems);`

Answer (score 0):

```
int getData(ifstream inFile, menuItemType* menuList, int numberOfItems);
```

declares a function inside `main()` (it works, and it actually hides the out-of-main declaration). You probably intend to *call* the `getData` function, like

```
getData(inFile, menuList, numberOfItems);
```

where `inFile`, `menuList`, `numberOfItems` are parameters which you must define/pass.

You also need to pass the `ifstream` by reference (as you cannot copy it), or otherwise `std::move` it when passing (the latter option is valid only in C++11).

Comment: This is what I did before but it is not affecting the runtime.

`int getData(ifstream& inFile, menuItemType* menuList, int& numberOfItems);`

Comment: you need to first do `ifstream inFile;` then pass `inFile` to your function, as mentioned in the answer. What you have right now is just a function declaration, not a function call.